# Как сделать, что бы строки в html таблице отображались в обратном порядке

Tags: php, html

Как сделать, что бы `tr` в `tbody` отображались в обратном порядке?

У меня есть html таблица, в которую выгружаются данные из БД. Но отображаются данные так, что всё новое, добавленное в БД, отображается в самом конце таблицы

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Имя</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Дата</th>
      <th>Сообщение</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($result as $res) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo $res->id; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $res->name; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $res->email; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $res->date; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $res->message; ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

использовать при формировании `$result` или в цикле `array_reverse`

```
<?php foreach (array_reverse($result) as $res) { ?>
```

Comment: Если данные выгружаются из БД, то их надо корректно сортировать, а не ворочать массивы на клиенте. `ORDER BY id DESC` в помощь.